# What will happen to classCounter Variable?

Tags: java, serialization

If I serialize this object and then again deserialize and get object what will be value of `classCounter`?

I created 5 object `classCounter = 5` what I will get in new object ?

```
Public Counter implements serializable {

 private static classCounter = 0;


Counter (){

 classCounter ++;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it will not affect the counter at all. More over if you transfer serialized data to jvm with different classloader it may occur that counter is less then 5.

Answer (score 0):

Default constructor is not called for Serializable classes on deserialization, so `classCounter++` is not called.
But you have to know, that default constructor **will** be called for superclasses if they don't implement Serializable. See explanation [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=251942).